# Replacing OpenShift with manual deployment

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

I have a server with OpenShift and Node.js installed and I would like to stop using OpenShift and go back to manually `git pull`.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can use your git commands.. did you try `git pull` on the local project level directory?

Comment: I've realized it's a bare repository, not sure how to use git commands on it.

Comment: Go to OpenShift web console, click on your application. 
On the right side, you will see a git source code url which looks like: ssh://1111e683f3d890a89e333f33@app-choi.rhc.com/~/git/app.git/. 

on local workspace, you can clone to the repository as follows: `git clone ssh://1111e683f3d890a89e333f33@app-choi.rhc.com/~/git/app.git/`